# How do I most securely funnel information from a 3rd party to a user?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, jwt

As a learning project I'm trying to build a project similar to the corona vaccine QR code app that we have in the Netherlands. And I have some questions around the most secure way to handle such sensitive/private data.

So I have a workflow in mind, which I want to lay out here and ask your opinions on. And I believe I can use JWT for part of my workflow. As far as I know, JWT can either be signed or encrypted. And maybe both, I'm not sure. I think I need to have an encrypted *and* signed JWT in the end. I don't fully understand how signing and encryption works, so I don't know what their limits are. Anyway, we have:

- The institution vaccinating people.
- The person getting vaccinated.
- The person who'd like to be able to verify whether or not someone was vaccinated.
- And finally my backend-server.

For short, I'll call them the vaccinator, the vaccinatee, the verifier and the server respectively. Here's what I believe the safest workflow would be.

1. Vaccinatee downloads my app on their phone.
2. Vaccinatee gets vaccinated and is then told to open my app on their phone.
3. If this is the first time the app has been opened then:

   1. The app generates a public/private key pair.
   2. The app sends a POST request to `https://myserver.com/api/register` with its public key.
   3. The server generates a new unique id for this device, stores it in the database's `users` table together with their public key and sends back a response with their id. The table now looks something like this:

| id | public_key | vaccination_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [unique id] | [user's public key] | NULL |

​

4. The app now shows a button that says "I just got vaccinated".
5. The vaccinatee taps the button.
6. The app generates a random 4 letter code and sends that to the server, which the server will store in a table as a temporary link to the device's id.
7. The app shows the 4 letter code on the phone's display.
8. The vaccinatee shows the code to the vaccinator.
9. The vaccinator fills that code into the form they were already filling in and finally sends a POST request to the server with data that looks something like this:`{"name":"John Doe","date":"2021-09-26","vaccination":"Pfizer","code":"SRTJ"}`
10. The server uses the code to figure out which user id this data is about. It then stores this json as an encrypted JWT using the user's public key and stores it in the `vaccination_data` column of this user.
11. The vaccinatee's app now shows a button that says "Get QR code".
12. When the vaccinatee taps that button, the app requests the encrypted JWT from the server.
13. It then saves the encrypted JWT in a file on the phone and decrypts it with the private key whenever the user wants to show a QR code.

So now the server's database only contains a bunch of random ids with encrypted data along-side it. I think that's anonymous and secure enough, right?

But now a few days later, the vaccinatee would like to go to an event where the organizer wants to verify whether or not they really got vaccinated. Here I'm not sure what is the best way to go about it. When the vaccinatee's app decrypts the JWT, the result can't just be a raw JSON, right? The result should actually be *another* JWT, but this time a JWT that's not encrypted, but signed. So that the phone that's scanning the QR code can actually verify that the QR code is legit. And preferably the verifier can do this without needing an internet connection.

So basically I have three questions:

1. Is the workflow I described here indeed safe? Or is there a big flaw I'm not seeing?
2. If this is indeed a good workflow, what is the canonical way to make a nested JWT, where the outer layer is an encrypted JWT, and the inner layer is a signed JWT?
3. And how does one choose between all the different algorithms there are available for signing and encrypting?

Comment: It seems like this discussion has punted on the most and really only important point: how does a verifier know whether someone is vaccinated or not?

Comment: This would make an interesting question on a forum-type website where you could have back-and-forth. Stackoverflow is *not* a forum however, so this question is not a great fit.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, got any forums you would recommend? :-)

Comment: Hmm, I think that this web page actually exactly answers my most important question: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/signed-and-encrypted-jwt

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for using HMAC with PKI.
You have 2 untrusted (the vaccinatee and the event organizer) entities, that need to form one-direction trust relations between them based on a higher authority that both of them trust (similar to how TLS certificate trust works)

1. The backend server stores a private-public keypair, the public key is shared with each entity that would like to verify proof of vaccination.
2. When the user get vaccinated, he give his phone number and get a digitally signed document via SMS.
3. The document is signed with the private key mentioned in #1, and include data that you want to verify (That's a signed JWT i.e. JWS)
4. The document could be encoded into a QR code image
5. Verification could be done by a different application that prefetches the public key from the server (so it's not required to be online), scanning the QR, decoding and verifying it with the public key.